# Unit Tests results are not appearing on the cruise control dashboard

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cruisecontrol.net

I have two projects in my solution both projects are for unit tests.
One of the project is working fine and showing results
[image: As you can see result are appearing]

But in the second project results are not appearing please see below image.
[image]

I am a beginner in unit Testing please give your input.

## any help would be appreciated.

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" xmlns="http://thoughtworks.org/ccnet/1/8">
  <cb:include href="Definitions.xml" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" />

  <cb:scope ProjectName="MCPWebsite">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1" queuePriority="6">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <cb:default_triggers />

      <sourcecontrol    type="svn">
        <cb:common_svn />
        <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)</workingDirectory>
        <trunkUrl>$(CollegeTrunkSVN)</trunkUrl>
      </sourcecontrol>

      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>MCPMain.sln</projectFile>
        </msbuild>

        <nunit>
          <cb:common_nunit />
          <assemblies>
            <assembly>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)\CollegeMVC\bin\CollegeMVC.dll</assembly>
          </assemblies>
          <excludedCategories>
            <excludedCategory>DBWrite</excludedCategory>
          </excludedCategories>
        </nunit>
      </tasks>

      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="NetPriceHelper">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="3">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

      <cb:default_triggers />

      <sourcecontrol    type="svn">
        <cb:common_svn />
        <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)</workingDirectory>
        <trunkUrl>$(CollegeTrunkSVN)</trunkUrl>
      </sourcecontrol>

      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>

        <nunit>
          <cb:common_nunit />
          <assemblies>
            <assembly>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)\bin\Debug\$(ProjectName).dll</assembly>
          </assemblies>
          <excludedCategories>
            <excludedCategory>DBWrite</excludedCategory>
            <excludedCategory>CommonDataSetScraper</excludedCategory>
          </excludedCategories>
          <!--<timeout units="minutes">45</timeout>-->
        </nunit>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="MyCollegePrice.CollegeTest">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol    type="svn">
        <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)</workingDirectory>
        <trunkUrl>$(CollegeTrunkSVN)</trunkUrl>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>

      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).sln</projectFile>
        </msbuild>

        <nunit>
          <cb:common_nunit />
          <assemblies>
            <assembly>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)\bin\Debug\$(ProjectName).dll</assembly>
          </assemblies>
          <excludedCategories>
            <excludedCategory>DBWrite</excludedCategory>
            <excludedCategory>CommonDataSetScraper</excludedCategory>
          </excludedCategories>
          <!--<timeout units="minutes">45</timeout>-->
        </nunit>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="NetPriceData">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="5">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

      <cb:default_triggers />

      <sourcecontrol    type="svn">
        <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <trunkUrl>$(CollegeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>

      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>

        <nunit>
          <cb:common_nunit />
          <assemblies>
            <assembly>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)\bin\Debug\$(ProjectName).exe</assembly>
          </assemblies>
          <excludedCategories>
            <excludedCategory>DBWrite</excludedCategory>
            <excludedCategory>NPC</excludedCategory>
            <excludedCategory>CommonDataSetScraper</excludedCategory>
          </excludedCategories>
        </nunit>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="CollegeData">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="2">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

      <cb:default_triggers />

      <sourcecontrol    type="svn">
        <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <trunkUrl>$(CollegeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>

      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>MyCollegePrice.$(ProjectName).sln</projectFile>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="PayscaleDatabaseAccess">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="2">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

      <cb:default_triggers />

      <sourcecontrol    type="svn">
        <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\LLBLDatabaseAccess\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <trunkUrl>$(CollegeTrunkSVN)/LLBLDatabaseAccess/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>

      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\LLBLDatabaseAccess\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>PayscaleData.csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>

        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\LLBLDatabaseAccess\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>PayscaleDataDBSpecific.csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="Zip4DatabaseAccess">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="2">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

      <cb:default_triggers />

      <sourcecontrol    type="svn">
        <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\LLBLDatabaseAccess\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <trunkUrl>$(CollegeTrunkSVN)/LLBLDatabaseAccess/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>

      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\LLBLDatabaseAccess\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>Zip4_Datafiles.csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>

        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\LLBLDatabaseAccess\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>Zip4_DatafilesDBSpecific.csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>

        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\LLBLDatabaseAccess\$(ProjectName)\DataAccess</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>CRZip4DataAccess.csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="NetPriceDataDB">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="2">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

      <cb:default_triggers />

      <sourcecontrol    type="svn">
        <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <trunkUrl>$(CollegeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>

      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>MyCollegePrice.$(ProjectName).csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(CollegeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>MyCollegePrice.$(ProjectName)DBSpecific.csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="vbhelper">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="2">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>

        <nunit>
          <cb:common_nunit />
          <assemblies>
            <assembly>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)\bin\$(ProjectName).dll</assembly>
          </assemblies>
        </nunit>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="shared">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="1">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\shpwebsitehelper</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>shpwebsitehelper.sln</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="SafeHomeSQLData">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="2">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>SHP.DataAdapter.sln</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="ParserHelper">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="3">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="shpwebsitehelper">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="4">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>

      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="QuickBooksHelper">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="3">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="ZipCodeUtil">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="3">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).sln</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
        <nunit>
          <cb:common_nunit />
          <assemblies>
            <assembly>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)\bin\debug\SagaraSoftware.$(ProjectName).dll</assembly>
          </assemblies>
        </nunit>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="nce.adodb">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="1">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/NCE/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\NCE\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\NCE\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).sln</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="nce.scripting">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="1">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/NCE/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\NCE\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\NCE\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).sln</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="ExcelLibrary">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="1">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).csproj</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="Pop3MimeClient">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="1">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).sln</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>

  <cb:scope ProjectName="PDFInvoiceParser">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" queue="Q1"  queuePriority="4">
      <webURL>$(WebUrlBase)$(ProjectName)/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
      <state type="state" directory="$(StateDir)" />
      <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactsDir)$(ProjectName)</artifactDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
      <cb:default_triggers />
      <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(SafeHomeTrunkSVN)/$(ProjectName)</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
        <cb:common_svn />
      </sourcecontrol>
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
          <cb:common_msbuild />
          <workingDirectory>$(SafeHomeTrunkDir)\$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>$(ProjectName).sln</projectFile>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
      <publishers>
        <cb:common_publishers />
        <cb:EmailPublisher />
      </publishers>
    </project>
  </cb:scope>




  </cruisecontrol>
```

"

Comment: Can you share you're ccnet.config file?  That might be a start to getting enough info here for someone to help.  It might be helpful for you to walk through the chain of things that must happen for the results to be displayed and see if any of those things are missing.

Comment: Chain of those things: 1.  Unit tests are being executed for this project  2.  xml test result output file is present.  3.  ccnet.config file has a merge element that targets that result file.

Comment: @ioscode .. thanks for the interest.. just shared my config file.